# Processing logs in Amazon EMR with or without using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming, emr

I have a lot of log files in my EMR cluster at path 'hdfs:///logs'. Each log entry is multiple lines but have a starting and ending marker to demarcate between two entries.
Now,

1. Not all entries in a log file are useful
2. the entries which are useful needs to be transformed and the output needs to be stored in an output file, so that I can efficiently query (using Hive) the output logs later.

I have a python script which can simply take a log file and do part a. and b. mentioned above but I have not written any mappers or reducers.

Hive takes care of Mappers and Reducers for its queries. Please tell me if and how it is possible to use the python script to run it over all logs and save the output in 'hdfs:///outputlogs' ?

I am new to Map Reduce and have seen some examples of Word count but all of them has a single input file. Where can I find examples which has multiple input files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I see that you have two-fold issue:

- **Having more than one file as input**

  The same word count example will work if you pass in more than one
  file as input. In fact you can very easily pass a `folder name` as
  input instead of a file name, in your case `hdfs:///logs`.

  you may even pass on a comma separated list of paths as input, for
  this instead of using following:

  `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));`

  You may use the following:

  `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, args[0]);`

  Note that only passing a list of comma separated as `args[0]` will be
  sufficient.
- **How to convert your logic to mapreduce**

  This does have a steep learning curve as you will need to think in
  terms of key and values. But I feel that you can just have all the
  logic in the mapper itself and have an `IdentityReducer`, like this :

  `conf.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);`

  If you spend sometime reading examples from the following locations,
  you should be in a better position to make these decisions:

  - [hadoop-map-reduce-examples](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/) ( http://hadoop-map-reduce-examples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hadoop-examples/src/ )
  - http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html
  - http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/
  - http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.in/2011/04/word-count-hadoop-map-reduce-example.html

Answer (score 1):

The long-term correct way to do this is, as Amar stated, to write a MapReduce job to do it.

However, if this is a one-time thing, and the data isn't too enormous, it might be simplest/easiest to do this with a simple bash script since you already have the python script:

```
hadoop fs -text /logs/* > input.log
python myscript.py input.log output.log
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal output.log /outputlogs
rm -f input.log output.log
```

If this is a repeated process - something you want to be reliable and efficient - or if you just want to learn to use MapReduce better, then stick with Amar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logic already written, and you want to do parallell processing using EMR and/or vanilla Hadoop - you can use Hadoop streaming : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html. In a nutshell - your script taking data into stdin and making output to stdout can became a mapper. 
 Thus you will run the processing of data in HDFS using cluster, without a need to repackage you code.